# What is the difference between grep -r and find here?

Tags: linux, grep, find, search, coreutils

I'm trying to recursively grep through files in a directory to find a certain string. The solution of my choice is:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep "string to find" {} \+
```

... while using grep recursively (like preferred by other unix users) will seemingly get stuck in an endless loop:

```
$ grep -r "string to find"
```

What is the difference beetween find and grep here? I'm using `GNU grep 3.4` and `GNU grep 2.7` compared with `GNU find 4.7.0` on `Linux 5.4.24` and an `ext4` file system, btw.

Comment: Are you sure it's `-r` that's hanging and not `-R`?

Comment: Please describe "will [...] get stuck in an endless loop". I think this is not normal behavior, it should work fine I guess ...

Comment: Grep is waiting on standard input since no file has been provided on command line. So no "endless loop" here, but a "endless wait". Try eating <ctrl-d> (EOF) and then it will return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `grep` command you are missing the FILE pattern, e.g. the current directory:

```
$ grep -r "string to find" .
```

Default behaviour for at least some Unices is to use standard input when it is missing.  From `man grep`: "grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name..."

EDIT: Sorry, I see now that the OP specifically mentions `GNU grep 3.4`.  This behaviour (using working directory instead of standard input) changed sometime after v 2.7, and I didn't catch up on that.  I'll leave the answer here as a lesson in not reading the question fully.

Comment: From `man grep` : `if  no  file  operand  is  given,  grep  searches  the   working directory.`

Comment: @pLumo: What system are you on?  On my Linuxes the following is stated in `man grep`: "grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name..."

Comment: @pLumo: I see now that OP specifically mentions  `GNU grep 3.4` and it specifically says what you quote.  But the problem still sounds very much like it's waiting for stdin.

Comment: I noticed that one of the servers I'm using this command on uses `GNU grep 2.7`. This answer does the trick. Thank you!